# Search wildcard with xpath in docx4j

Tags: java, xpath, saxon, docx4j, xpath-2.0

Hi is it possible to search wildcard with xpath in docx4j?

consider this example:

```
<w:r>
    <w:rPr>
       <w:lang w:bidi="fa-IR" />
    </w:rPr>
    <w:t>priority: {priority}</w:t>
</w:r>
<w:r>
    <w:rPr>
       <w:lang w:bidi="fa-IR" />
    </w:rPr>
    <w:t>{effectiveLocations}</w:t>
</w:r>
```

I need to find all runs with text contains ***{*}***, this means I need to get both runs in example above.

but docx4j use XPath 1.0, so it does not support matches query, any other way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

https://docx4java.org/docx4j/docx4j-nightly-20181009.jar contains https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/commit/cab8adcb768c18103e7a9b48ac39dc8fcde5ff0c

So if you have on your classpath https://search.maven.org/artifact/net.sf.saxon/Saxon-HE/9.9.0-1/jar

You can do something like:

```
XPathFactoryUtil.setxPathFactory(
        new net.sf.saxon.xpath.XPathFactoryImpl());
```